# How to update previous state to a new date

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate, use-state, react-typescript

I'm working on a react-native project and I am using `mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker`

To change state I am doing this,

```
export default = () => {
const [getDate, setGetDate] = useState(null)
const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisible] = useState(false)

const showDatePicker = () => setDatePickerVisible(true);
const hideDatePicker = () => setDatePickerVisible(false);

const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    setGetDate(format(new Date(date), 'MM/dd/yyy'));
    hideDatePicker();
  }
}

//This is how I'm implementing the datepicker with React Hook Form.
{isDatePickerVisible ? (
 <Controller
    control={control}
    render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
        mode="date"
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
        onCancel={hideDatePicker}
       />
     )}
     name="apptDate"
     rules={{ required: true }}
     defaultValue=""
      />
   ) : ( 
      <Controller
        control={control}
        render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onTouchEnd={showDatePicker}
            onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
            value={getDate}
          />
        )}
        name="apptDate"
        rules={{ required: true }}
        defaultValue=""
      />
     )
}
```

When I open the modal and press Confirm on today's date (the current date) it returns `null` but after the second time I get the date I want.

I believe it's because I'm not updating the previous state using the function way to update the state and I'm having trouble figuring out how to update the previous state of `null` to the `new Date()` as a function.

Comment: I suspect your question might be a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately

Comment: Could you provide all code of your component to see problem?

Comment: Updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code.

Does your code look like this?

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import {format} from 'date-fns';

const App = () => {
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisible] = useState(false);
  const [getDate, setGetDate] = useState(null);
  const showDatePicker = () => setDatePickerVisible(true);

  const hideDatePicker = () => setDatePickerVisible(false);

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    setGetDate(format(new Date(date), 'MM/dd/yyy'));
    hideDatePicker();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={showDatePicker} style={styles.button}>
          <Text>Open Date Time Picker</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{getDate}</Text>
        <DateTimePickerModal
          isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
          mode="date"
          onConfirm={handleConfirm}
          onCancel={hideDatePicker}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    padding: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});
```

You can find whole project from [my github](https://github.com/DarkPonyBee/stackoverflow-update-status-datepicker).

Comment: Yeah, this is close to what I have. I'm using react-hook-form to have a textInput to open the modal and display the date inside it. I'm trying to do exactly what you do with the first selection

Comment: If you still have issues, please add full code.

Comment: I've updated the question to included my code(from memory I'll have to look tomorrow at work) that I'm working with. Using React Hook Form along with it.

Comment: @masterbro. Please let me know if you still have issues.